# Error on place order in magento 2

Tags: checkout, error, magento-2.1.3, server-setup, place-order

While placing an order, there is an error occurred like this:

> "an error occurred on the server please try to place the order again"

then the cart becomes empty and we need to again add the product.

I don't get this error all time. When I place order in some time I face this problem. [image: Error]

**Error log:**

```
[2017-05-24 10:22:56] main.INFO: Theme layout update file '/var/www/html/m2/app/design/frontend/Mobac/porto/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml' is not valid.
Extra content at the end of the document
 Line: 23 [] []
[2017-05-24 10:22:56] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_463d019c92f3536ffbf7da4ca76d7b2e8 and handles sales_email_order_items: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-05-24 10:22:57] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail.  [] []
[2017-05-24 10:23:01] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Comment: Please enable magento log and see what happen.With log it is too difficult to tell u the error

Comment: @ Amit Bera Please check updated query included the log

Comment: @Amith This error comes sometimes because of Your shipping method is not proper set. Sometimes in checkout shipping form data are auto fillup, at that time shipping method are not updated so this type of error are display in payment method after place order.

Comment: @ Rakesh Jesadiya but some time its working with out any problem